# invoking AWS lambda python function from an existing lambda function gives error

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

can anyone help me to troubleshoot below error while invoking child lambda function from parent function in same region. I have referred online for this received error `'Database' object is not callable` and no help found related to this error.

```
    import certifi
    import os, sys
    from pymongo import MongoClient
    import yaml, time
    from api_helper import ApiPy
    import pyotp
    import json, requests
    from signal import signal, SIGPIPE, SIG_DFL
    signal(SIGPIPE,SIG_DFL)
    import boto3
    client = boto3.client('lambda')

    ca = certifi.where()
    client =  MongoClient("mongodb+srv://user:pass@ap-southeast-1.6dds33.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority", tlsCAFile=ca)
    db = client['ap-southeast-1']

    api = ApiPy()
    with open('cred.yml') as f:
        cred = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
        f.close()

    token = cred['factor2']

    socket_opened = False
    ret = api.login(userid = cred['user'], password = cred['pwd'], twoFA=pyotp.TOTP(token).now(), vendor_code=cred['vc'], api_secret=cred['apikey'], imei=cred['imei'])

    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        try:
            ret = api.get_positions()
        except:
            ret = api.login(userid = cred['user'], password = cred['pwd'], twoFA=pyotp.TOTP(token).now(), vendor_code=cred['vc'], api_secret=cred['apikey'], imei=cred['imei'])
            ret = api.get_positions()
        if ret:
            collection = db["mydbss"]
            collection.create_index("tsym", unique=True)
            for z in ret:
                if int(z['openbuyqty']) != 0:
                    try:
                        collection.insert_one(z)
                    except:
                        collection.update_one({'tsym':z['tsym']}, {'$set': {"openbuyqty": z["openbuyqty"]}}, upsert=False) 
                else:
                    collection.delete_one({"tsym": z['tsym']})
            
        else:
            response = client.invoke(FunctionName="arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1:0000000:function:childfunction", InvocationType='RequestResponse')
            result = json.loads(response.get('body').read())
            return result
```

response

```
    {
      "errorMessage": "'Database' object is not callable",
      "errorType": "TypeError",
      "stackTrace": [
        "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 53, in lambda_handler\n    response = client.invoke(FunctionName=\"arn:aws:lambda:ap-southeast-1:00000000:function:childfunction\", InvocationType='RequestResponse')\n"
      ]
    }

    Function Logs
    OpenBLAS WARNING - could not determine the L2 cache size on this system, assuming 256k
    START RequestId: 89c79357-bf04-4523-9f56-3673bdh362d Version: $LATEST
    [ERROR] TypeError: 'Database' object is not callable
```

child function:

```
    def lambda_handler(event, context):
        return {
            "body" : "tested successfully"
        }
```

Kindly help.

Comment: what is `client`?

Comment: updated my question, it's boto3.client

Comment: This does not seem to be the code producing the error. Please double check your code and the error.

Comment: How are you using OpenBLAS and do you have any variables named `Database` that we can't see?

Comment: @jarmod i have added the full code, and OpenBLAS is a just a warning, but my error is related to client.invoke(FunctionName=

Comment: @Marcin Full code is added here but code fails at else condition .. i am not sure why

Comment: You have two `client` variables. The MongoDB client overwrites the AWS Lambda client.

Comment: @jarmod Excellent, i didnt see that, now it works fine after i change client variable for boto3. please provide the answer, i will mark as complete

Comment: Guess why I asked what `client` was my very first comment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you accidentally have two `client` objects:

```
client = boto3.client('lambda')
...
client = MongoClient("mongodb+...", tlsCAFile=ca)
```

The latter replaces the former, so when you subsequently make a call to the AWS Lambda SDK via `client`, that object is of type [Database](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/database.html) rather than being an actual [AWS Lambda client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/lambda.html#client).

Comment: thanks it works fine after i change the variable for boto3